# Interpolation is not working with click method

Tags: angular

I need to use interpolation inside click but its not working , I am also tried ng-click same problem occurred.

```
<li *ngFor="let link of dataService.roleNav[dataService.getRoleId()]" (click) ="{{link.method}}">
       {{ link.data }}
</li>
```

Comment: Could you provide more info (preferably the code) of your `dataService`? What is `roleNav` and `getRoleId()` definition. Does it returns `Observable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

**Solution 1**

```
link = {
  data : 'abc',
  method: () => this.YourMethod()
}
```

HTML:

```
<li *ngFor="let link of dataService.roleNav[dataService.getRoleId()]" (click) ="link.method()">
      {{ link.data }}
</li>
```

**Solution 2** ( If you cannot change the json )

HTML:

```
<li *ngFor="let link of testData" (click)="callMethod(link.method)">
    {{ link.data }}
</li>
```

TS:

```
  callMethod(methodName: string) {
    this[methodName]();
  }
```

**See [Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5ll21a?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: I want to loop link this

<li *ngFor="let link of dataService.roleNav[dataService.getRoleId()]" ng-click ="link.method">
                <a>
                    <span><img alt="{{link.data}}" src="../../../assets/img/{{link.src}}" class="menuIcon"></span>
                    {{ link.data}}
                </a>
            </li>

Comment: Yes, this will work. Show `dataService.roleNav[dataService.getRoleId()]` output

Comment: @Diya ng-click works in angularjs for angular it should be (click)

Comment: @Diya I have modified the demo and it has loop, check.

Comment: @Diya, show the complete code that you have tried. It is working in the demo.

Comment: link.method is a function name not a function

Comment: This is the array which am trying to loop

[{method: 'onClickDashBoard', src: 'dashboard.png', data: 'DashBoard'},
                        {method: 'onClickManageUser', src: 'manage-user.png', data: 'Manage User'},
                        {method: 'onClickLeads', src: 'leads.png', data: 'Leads'},
                        {method: 'onClickTarget', src: 'target.png', data: 'Target'},
                        {method: 'onClickQuotation', src: 'quotation.png', data: 'Quotation'},
                        
}]

Comment: You have to modify it to a function

Comment: @Diya, try the second method in the demo

Answer (score 0):

Create method to get method reference from your component something like

```
 getFunctionReference(method){
   return this[method]
 }
```

Then change your code to

```
<li *ngFor="let link of dataService.roleNav[dataService.getRoleId()]" (click) ="getFunctionReference(link.method)()">
               {{ link.data }}
</li>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-an1ch2)

Comment: link.method is not a function , it is just a function name